# How can I copy the message-body of a POST?

Tags: firefox

I'm running some tests of my webapp in Firefox Quantum (60.0.2).

I fill out a form, and submit it.  This sends a POST request with an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` message-body to my APP.

When I use `Tools / Web Developer / Network Tools` to inspect the request, the `Params` tab shows the *decoded* values that were present in the message-body of the request.

What I want, in this context, is to load the urlencoded content into my paste buffer.

- `Copy POST Data` gives me a decoded copy of the information
- `Copy as cURL` gives me a curl command with all of the headers, but the `--data` argument is an empty string.

What's the right way to get the raw message body?

Answer (score 0):

[Copy All As HAR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#CopySave_All_As_HAR) loads into the paste buffer an [HTTP Archive](https://w3c.github.io/web-performance/specs/HAR/Overview.html), which is a JSON representation of the "HTTP transactions" of your session.  `entries[].request.postData.text` seems to be what you want.

In my experiments, you also get `entries[].request.postData.params[]`, but according to the 1.2

> Note that text and params fields are mutually exclusive.

So, good luck?